# Get DOM nodes using jQuery, then output them to comma-separated string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab all DOM nodes and then output them as a string, but the output is `HTML Collection` format:

```
[html, head, meta, title, body, h1, p]
```

Instead, I would like to output this as a simple string:

```
"html, head, meta, title, body, h1, p"
```

Here is my current jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    console.log(allNodes);
});
```

Comment: So `map()` their `this.tagName`, and then join them with `', '`

Comment: @Taplar, thanks....can you put code into an answer?

Comment: Or you could answer your own question, :)

Comment: Haha....great thank you.  I appreciate the direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Taplar pointed out while I was typing, you'll want to use `Array#map` to retrieve the `tagName` attribute. However, there's a very small extra step that's missing.

`HTMLCollection`s don't have a `.map()` method. To account for this, you have to convert the `HTMLCollection` to an array of `HTMLElement`s first.

That's more work than it's worth, though. Since you're already using jQuery, the better solution is to change your vanilla JS selector into a jQuery one, which can chain everything together in one line.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log($('*').get().map(v=>v.tagName).join(', '));
});
```

You could also use `$.map` if you're that loyal to jQuery, but I reckon performance would be the same *at best*.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log($.map($('*'),v=>v.tagName).join(', '));
});
```

If you don't feel like using jQuery here for whatever reason, my initial answer using vanilla JavaScript is below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    console.log(Array.from(allNodes).map(v=>v.tagName).join(', '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A reusable solution using jQuery (and three Plain JavaScript methods), with the option of filtering out tags as well in one line (albeit a long line).

1. Find all tags of document:

   ```
   $(document).find('*')
   ```
2. Filter any undesired tags*:

   ```
   $(document).find('*').not('style, script')
   ```
3. Convert jQuery Collection into an array:

   ```
   $(document).find('*').not('style, script').toArray()
   ```
4. Map through the array and return the `tagName` from each element:

   ```
   $.map($(document).find('*').not('style, script').toArray(), (tag => tag.tagName))
   ```
5. Convert the resulting array into a string delimited by a comma and space:

   ```
   $.map($(document).find('*').not('style, script').toArray(), (tag => tag.tagName)).join(', ');
   ```
6. Format string:

   ```
   JSON.stringify($.map($(selector).find('*').not(filter).toArray(), (tag => tag.tagName)).join(', ')).toLowerCase();
   ```

The function `tagList(selector, filter = null)` does the above. First parameter is the parent, second parameter is optional* -- it can be ignored.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Index</h1>
  <p>Test</p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const tagList = (selector, filter = null) => JSON.stringify($.map($(selector).find('*').not(filter).toArray(), (tag => tag.tagName)).join(', ')).toLowerCase();

    console.log(tagList(document, 'script, style'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```